# How to add error message below UiTextField in swift programatically?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uilabel

Currently, i'm trying to add error message below UITextField.

I create my own UITextField class to make it reusable in every UITextField

But if i use the code below. The error message shown, but not responsively drag the other UITextfield to go down.

In this case, i don't want to define UILabel manually in XIB for every text field. Also, i don't want to give space between textfield. My expectation is the space (between each textfield) is created when error message shown.

Is there any way to do something like this ?

```
func setupErrorMessage() {

            /* Here, I am using AutoLayout to lay out the errorMessage on the screen.
               If you used storyboard, delete every line in this function except where
               we set the message to hidden */

        //self is uitextfield

        self.errorMessage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.errorMessage.text = "Error Message"
        self.errorMessage.textColor = .red
        self.errorMessage.isHidden = true
        self.addSubview(self.errorMessage)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
                self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0)
            ])
        }
```

And below is my XIB design

[image]

**Expectation**

Before

[image]

After (error message show and space created when message error shown)
[image]

Comment: to add view to stackView use addArrangedSubview or insertArrangedSubview

Comment: @aiwiguna is it possible to add view to stackview inside uitextfield class?  like uitextfield access parent stackview?

Comment: to access parent view use self.superview and downcasting it to UIStackView , if let stack = textfiled.superview as? UIStackView { stack.addArrangedSubview (error) }